# How to reach leaf from inside of unique id React Native Firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase and trying to make a query which is bring the coordinates whose "description" is "home",but there is autogenerated key and i dont know how to do it.

```
coordinates
-MZmXW7x1FNwW_fdsoyD
        description:"Home"
        latitude:1.111111
        longitude:1.111111
-MZwsZB_tkR8LBaXIcuX
-MZxClKmegPXoJTcZdcW
-MZxD3CVuHKmXcWOSBWr
-M_FtCqPhd26eiXwJpyO
```

I tried this code but i reach all of unique id's and unnecessary leaves.

```
getItems = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('/coordinates')
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) here, which allows you to order and filter data. In this case, that'd be:

```
firebase.database().ref('/coordinates')
  .orderByChild('description').equalTo('Home');
  .once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      console.log(child.val());
    })
  });
```

To ensure the query gets executed on the server, you'll want to [add an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) to your security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "coordinates": {
      ".indexOn": "description"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply,i'll also add index.